# set expiry time to some past value

Tags: apache

I am adding response header in `cache-control "no-cache"` in httpd.conf file, I also want to set expiry to some old time, lets say past 1 hour.

I am able to add `Expiry` header in below way
`<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType application/json "access 0 hour 0 minutes 0 seconds"
</IfModule>`

Can someone please suggest how I set time to `-n` hour.